# How can I plot a map of a specfic country using plotly

Tags: matplotlib, plotly, geopandas

Using geopandas and matplotlib I have ploted a map of india showing Air Quality Index.

The link to my data is:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-xihM-LCB6dNfONbK28CJWOP_PVgXA8C/view?usp=share_link

I want to plot an interactive map with names of the cities and borders of regions of India using plotly?

```
from matplotlib import cm, colors
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

#restricted to India.
ax = world[world.name == 'India'].plot(color='grey', edgecolor='white')

city_day_gdf.plot(column='AQI_Bucket', ax=ax, cmap='PuBuGn', markersize=city_day_gdf['AQI'])
norm = colors.Normalize(city_day_gdf.AQI.min(), city_day_gdf.AQI.max())
plt.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm,cmap='PuBuGn'), ax=ax)
plt.title("A Map showing the descriptions of Air Quality Index in terms of AQI magnitude across India between 2015 and 2020")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Which item would you like to color-code by the most recent date?

Answer (score 0):

- you can scatter your data using `px.scatter_mapbox()`.  Have reduced data to just newest reading per city.  You have not stated how you want to treat time series
- with requirement for plotting regions of India, you need some geometry for this.  Have used *GeoJson* from a repo on **GitHub** for this.  Have simplified the geometry as it is very detailed and hence will slow down **plotly** significantly
- finally pull it all together, layer scatter on top of choropleth

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.wkt
import plotly.express as px
import requests

url = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-xihM-LCB6dNfONbK28CJWOP_PVgXA8C/view?usp=share_link"
df = pd.read_csv("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=" + url.split("/")[-2], index_col=0)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
# just reduce data to last date for each city.   Nothing in question indicates
# how to dela with time series
df = df.sort_values(["City", "Date"]).groupby("City", as_index=False).last()

# get some geometry for regions of india
gdf_region = gpd.read_file(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Subhash9325/GeoJson-Data-of-Indian-States/master/Indian_States"
)
gdf_region["geometry"] = (
    gdf_region.to_crs(gdf_region.estimate_utm_crs())
    .simplify(5000)
    .to_crs(gdf_region.crs)
)
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    gdf_region,
    geojson=gdf_region.__geo_interface__,
    locations=gdf_region.index,
    color="NAME_1",
).update_traces(showlegend=False)


fig.add_traces(
    px.scatter_mapbox(
        df, lat="Lat", lon="Lon", color="AQI_Bucket", hover_data=["City"]
    ).data
)

fig.update_layout(
    mapbox=dict(
        style="carto-positron",
        zoom=3,
        center=dict(lat=df["Lat"].mean(), lon=df["Lon"].mean()),
    )
)
```

[image]